# Why is god said to be giver of good times and good things when our own Karma created it?

Tags: karma

This is a very confusing thing I see in Indian religions.

They say one's own karma is the cause of both joy (in whichever form, be it mental joy, materialistic joy, money, gold, relationships, etc, or even spiritual bliss)
as well as the cause of one's suffering (again be it of any type).

But if I am the maker of my own destiny via my own karma, then where does god even come into the picture here?

Why is God said to be the giver of wealth as in

> "That great, birthless Self is the eater of food and the giver of
> wealth (the fruits of one's work)" (Brhadaranyaka Upanishad 4.4.24)

I seriously don't get it.

I am the one doing my karma, so I reap my fruit. Why is it said, "God is a blessing" to me then?

Also, if God indeed is a giver, then why doesn't he give to everyone? Why some are more fortunate than others?

Comment: earth has soil, rivers have water, sun provides heat - using all these, plants grow. without earth, river or sun, plants cannot grow. but what type of plant grows depends completely on its seed. karma is the seed (specific cause), god is earth/river/sun (common cause). Without god, neither good nor bad karma can be done by anyone, but whether you plant good seed or bad seed, and get good fruits or bad fruits, is up to the farmer.

Comment: suppose think of beign born with physical deformity or dumb or deaf or blind would be able to do what you do now.. who gave you the body.. which working properly.. think of animals except humans born with hand, intellect to communicate and speach. if one is born animal what happens would be able to perform what you are doing.. okai everythin is fine suddenly some people have stoke.. would he able to operate as usual even walk upright requires gods grace and 72000 devathas sitting inside nadi is allowed to work for the god inside. but you are not aware. who triggers sexual

Comment: desire at appropriate age why cant the same desire present in children.. why people of opposite sex in the same type of birth gets attracted why cant cat got attracted to dog.. so everything is designed and operated according to wish of god.. first observe the world how it works in sequence why night 12 hrs why cannot be like norway. .why should earth revolve why cannot earth stay and rotate around the like moon which is circle the earth does because the other side of the moon we never see.. why cannot earth behave the same.. if ask question for everythin and ponder everythin is designed..

Answer (score 1):

I have thought about this question myself. Karma is classified into Sanchita, Prarabdha and Aagami karmas. That is, certain karmas are for experiencing in this birth itself, certain others in subsequent births, certain are mutable (changeable) and certain others immutable.

Every human born on earth is like a student. Like in a class, there are good students, mediocre ones and poor ones, likewise, some of us learn our lessons quickly, some take a long time and some do not learn even from trials and tribulations. A degree of free will is available to all of us in changing our karmas, if we do not exercise it, we become poor students.

When a student of life is a good one, and learns his lessons quickly, that portion of praarabhdha karma (the karma to experience in this life) which is mutable, gets changed by divine will. Note, this only happens to those good students, who have learnt their lessons! At this point, owing to the will of god, the person gets motivated by circumstances to try harder, to overcome obstacles and succeed. This change in destiny for good is willed by god, and that is why, he is eventually able to succeed!

This is why we say, all good things come from god!